# Rider with SQL Server - The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using SSL encryption

Tags: sql-server, rider

I installed SQL2019 and SQL Server Management Studio.
SQL Server with name "TESTINSTANCE" is running.

When I press "Test Connection" then I get this error:

> [08S01] The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:9d6e6b90-bd20-4364-b0e4-bfbdd6bc57c8 unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

It seems like my solution would be tab SSH/SSL -> Use SSL, but I don't know where should I get certificate files. Maybe it's something else, I don't know.

**UPDATE**:

All my first attempts was without "Use SSL", it doesn't work either.

Jdbc driver is installed by Rider by default.

Server=LEKRET\TESTINSTANCE don't work (Incorrect driver and/or database URL specified).

**UPDATE 2**:

Well, I finally found where I can enable Trust Server Certificate, in Advanced Options. Not ideal, but everything is on local machine so it should be fine.

Password and login didn't work, but I finally managed to create login with windows auth in SSMS.

After 8 hours it's finally working.

[image]

Comment: Did you try unchecking Use SSL on the SSH/SSL tab?  Are you intentionally using a jdbc driver?  Can you connect with the Jetbrains or Microsoft driver?  What happens if you put `Server=LEKRET\TESTINSTANCE` in the URL box?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't trust the certificate that SQL Server is using. You should try to get a certificate from a public or private CA that would be trusted by your machine. Failing that, select `Trust Server Certificate` in the `Options`, this is not ideal from a security point of view

Comment: SQL Server instances are installed, by default, with a self-signed X.509 certificate. While it is possible to acquire a CA-signed (or organization-signed) X.509 certificate and configure SQL Server to use it another thing you could do, if you have access to the remote machine on which the SQL Server instance resides, is to export the public key portion of its X.509 certificate to a .crt file and then import that into your own Personal or Trusted Root certificate stores. That allows you to verify the identity of that specific SQL Server without blindly trusting any old (MiTM-able) server.